# Martial arts movie about students at a high school(?)

Tags: story-identification, movie, martial-arts

If I remember correctly the movie was sometime between 1995-2005. I don't remember it being in English but was subtitled. The main language may have been Japanese. For some reason, I think the title had the words "High School" in it. The entire setting takes place at the school.
The story centered around a young man that was rather shy but very adept at martial arts. Several scenes involved him being picked on by other students. The most significant scene that sticks in my head is in the big fight towards the end of the movie. The scene is outside and as the characters start to fight it begins raining. During the fight, the two characters will hit each other so hard that the rain is displaced due to the impact (very much like the fight between Neo and Agent Smith in "Matrix: Revolutions").